# How do I restore the MS Word file associations after installing LibreOffice?

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, libreoffice

I have installed LibreOffice because it is the word processing application used by my son's school. But I've noticed after the installation that Microsoft Word file types are now associated with LibreOffice.

How can I restore the Microsoft Word program associations while keeping the LibreOffice file types, such as .ODT, associated with LibreOffice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on a docx or doc file and select open with then choose default program. Word should be an option on the dialog. Select it and check the "always use the selected program to open this kind of file" checkbox. There used to be a dialog that lets you see a list of all file types and select the associated program, but I don't remember how to get to that anymore.

Comment: Easy as pie and worked great. Thank you sir -

Comment: No problema! Wish all problems were this simple ;)